# Does clicking a link always cause a full-page re-rendering?

Tags: html, dom, browser

Here's a scenario: Page1.html and page2.html are identical, except a change of a single word.

**page1.html**

```
 <html><head></head><body>
 Lorem ipsum *one*
 ...Stuff here...
 <a href="page2.html">click me</a>
 ...Stuff here...
 </body></html>
```

**page2.html**

```
 <html><head></head><body>
 Lorem ipsum *two*
 ...Stuff here...
 <a href="page1.html">click me</a>
 ...Stuff here...
 </body></html>
```

As you can see, everything is identical in both pages except that in `page2.html`, `*one*` is swapped with `*two*`

Now, assume a visitor visits `page1.html`, and clicks on the `a href` link, will the browser re-render the entire DOM or simply detect the changed word and modify it?

This is obviously implementation specific, my interest is an answer for the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE...)

Comment: The entire page will be reloaded

Comment: Ajax is a popular choice for targeted changes while avoiding full-scale reloading

Comment: Assuming no JS code is involved, then yes, clicking a link makes the browser "leave" the current page, and load whatever page that the link is targeting.

Comment: To know that only a part of the page has changed would require the client to retrieve it in its entirety... so might as well render it completely.

Comment: To me it seems this sounds like a rather simple browser optimization ("As long as the bytes in the html page being downloaded match the bytes in the html page the user is currently seeing, do not re-render that part"), are you people certain no browsers do this? why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will, unless you change your link click to a javascript that loads an inner HMTL dinamically. This is called Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I will surely load the entire page...A href requests basically reload the complete page..you can still load part of the page using Asynchronous javascript and xml... AJAX :)

Answer (score 0):

It will attempt to reload the page.

If you want to stop the default action of reloading the page you could use `event.preventDefault();`.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/][1](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

**@Rodrigogq sums it pretty much up.**

I would recommend using **jQuery** for replacing text.

`$('body').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("one", "two");
});​​​​​`

This wouldn't use ajax but simply replace. 
Can be modified to a button press.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is changed the browser loads the data from new address and needs to render it again – regardless of implementation of the browser. The difference between the HTML documents would be visible not earlier than when the new document would be loaded ant parsed into DOM which means that it gets rendered rather than finding the differences (which would be non-trivial task).

If you want to change only the content of particular element you need to use Javascript and set either static value or load it via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

To answer:
"As long as the bytes in the html page being downloaded match the bytes in the html page the user is currently seeing, do not re-render that part"

» Here is what it looks like in most browsers:
Step 1: Click on a link
Step 2: Get head response from the destination server (good if there is content-length included)
Step 3: If response is render-able (usually 200), Start unloading the already loaded DOM.
Step 4: Load the new content and render.

This prohibits any byte level comparison with the current and new request to identify the difference.

Comment: I actually meant DOM-level comparisons, sorry for using "bytes".